# Can't get perl scripts to work (500 internal server error) on a tuxlite LAMP stack (Debian 6 Squeeze)

Tags: perl, debian, lamp

Does anyone who has experience with Tuxlite know how to get Perl scripts working? I've tried many, many things from tutorials on the web about getting Perl scripts to work with Apache without success. I keep getting a 500 internal server error. I'm allowing .cgi and .pl scripts in .htaccess.

My script is a hello world script

`#!/usr/bin/perl print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"; print "Hello World.";`

Comment: check your error logs?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary in the error logs. I'm new to this, so I don't know if I have to enable perl to work in apache or something. I'm still looking things up.

Comment: have you started your httpd service?

Comment: Yeah. I must be missing something really obvious.

Comment: An ISE often means that your script threw an error.. or didn't send valid headers. The error logs should contain that information.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you're right. I get "Premature end of script headers" in the error log. The script is fine, permissions are fine, the file was uploaded in ASCII and perl is installed, so I don't know what would be causing it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is not a apache/web problem.

Try your script on the shell and check the output. 
(I assume that it does not run in the shell.)

May be your perl is not set up or a module is missing.

If that works, please add your script to your question.

Comment: I am using just a hello world script. perl -wc helloworld.pl says "symtax OK" and perl -w helloworld.pl gives me "#!/usr/bin/perl print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"; print "<html><body><h1>Hello World.</h1></body></html>";" which is my script code.

Comment: I would assume that perl -w helloworld.pl gives you the output:  Content-Type: text/html  <html><body><h1>Hello World.</h1></body></html>